# HTTP: Key-Value-Pairs in POST-Parameters (in URL) or Headerfield

Tags: http, url, post, header, key-value

I am looking for a way to send Key-Value pairs from a client to a server using http (POST). What of the both possibilities would you recommend and why? Does the size of the respective URL or header-field matter (what are the sizes exactly, are there any definitions?)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When browsers send a POST from a standard HTML form, they are sending parameters and values that are effectively key-value pairs--as the body of the POST request.  The standard format for this includes standard delimiters, e.g. `object=triangle&chosen+action=flip`, which requires escaping if your keys or values contain them.  The standard HTTP libraries for extracting the parameters will expect this, and any limitations on lengths will be specific to those libraries and server specifications.  However, it is perfectly acceptable to use any format for data in the body of the POST request.  The conventions are actually more specific to the HTML standard.

Comment: What if I have already something in the body? Will it work, too?

Comment: What goes into an HTML form from the input tags are generally called parameters.  If that's what you mean by already having something in the body, then you might consider encoding your key-value pairs into a single additional parameter.